# How to create web dynamic project in eclipse

Tags: eclipse, web-services, eclipse-plugin

I found a lot of tutorials how to create Dynamic Web Project in Eclipse but everywhere
it is recomended to put name of the project, choose target runtime, dynamic web module version and configuration option(I want "CXF web services Project"). I set that options. In every tutorial is said i should clik finish after that. But my finish button is disabled. What is wrong? I use Eclipse Kepler Service Release 1. Its raw instalation without any new plug-ins.

Answer (score 0):

By choosing "CXF web services Project" in configuration option we are obligated to link to Eclipse some apache CXF framework files first. The download is here: http://cxf.apache.org/download.html. And we can import that in menu(Window->Preferences->Web Services->CXF 2.x Preferences. That solved the problem. I hope that would be useful for beginers.